# React grid not rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-grid-layout

In React, I am trying to create a basic grid using https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout.

I have created two rectangles and I have given them a layout like this:

```
<ReactGridLayout layout={{x:1, y:1, w:5, h:10}}>
  <div key={1} style={{width: "500px", height: "100px", border: "1px solid #000", bgcolor: "blue", color: "green"}}>
    Rectangle 1
  </div>

  <div key={2} style={{width: "500px", height: "100px", border: "1px solid #000", bgcolor: "blue", color: "green"}}>
    Rectangle 2
  </div>
</ReactGridLayout>
```

However, instead of the rectangles, this is displayed:

[image]

Any ideas about what could cause this failure?

Answer (score 1):

Your layout doesn't match what the [README says](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout#grid-layout-props) it should be. It's supposed to be an array of layout objects, one object for each content entry. You've provided a single object, without any array wrapping around it.

You probably want something like this:

```
var React = require('react');

var hash = require('hashfunctionofsomesort');

var MyGrid = React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps: function() {
    divcontent: [
      "rectangle 1",
      "rectangle 2"
    ],
    defaultLayout: {
      x: ..., y: ..., w: ..., h: ...
    }
  },
  generateDivs: function() {
    return this.props.divcontent.map(function(content) {
      return <div key={hash(content)}>{content}</div>;
    });
  },
  generateLayouts: function() {
    var defaultLayout = this.props.defaultLayout;
    var divs = this.props.divcontent;
    return divs.map(function(div, index) {
      var layout = defaultLayout;
      // basically generate a layout here. Whatever values work for you.
      layout.y = index;
      return layout;
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    var layouts = this.generateLayouts();
    var divs = this.generateDivs();
    return <ReactGridLayout layout={layouts}>{divs}</ReactGridLayout>;
  }
});
```

So: one layout per div, and do keys right: keys are supposed to be indicative of the component you're keying, is if your key is based on the order you specified the element in, you're doing keys wrong. The point of keys is to allow fast diffing, using ordering as if they're keys means that if you reorder your keys, instead of React going "these elements just got swapped" it sees full property and content updates for both elements, making things a lot slower.